# How does the `find-partner` procedure in Preferential Attachment work?

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I have a netlogo model that has separate procedures to set up both a small world and erdos-renyi network. The user can specify which network to create and the number of nodes for each of these by using sliders to specify the numbers of each breed they want e,g for my erdos renyi network...

My model is used to simulate the spread of measles through a network

```
   to setup-erdos-renyi
  clear-all
  ;; Make a circle of turtles
  set num-nodes (num-children + num-adults + num-toddlers)
    create-children num-children
    create-adults num-adults
    create-toddlers num-toddlers 

  layout-circle turtles (max-pxcor - 8)
  ;; Now give each pair of turtles an equal chance
  ;; of creating a link
  ask turtles [
    ;; we use "self > myself" here so that each pair of turtles
    ;; is only considered once
    create-links-with turtles with [self > myself and random-float 1.0 < probability]

  ]


setup
  infect-initial



     ask links [set closed? false]
        display




        reset-ticks

    end
```

What I'd like to do is implement the option to simulate preferential attachment between these turtles.

I've been looking at the supplied preferential attachment model that comes in built in Netlogo, but I'm having a hard time applying this to my model. What I am really struggling to understand is how

```
to-report find-partner
  report [one-of both-ends] of one-of links
end
```

This snippet serves to find each node a partners in the example model, is this based on the number of links a mode already has thus causing the preferential attachment?

I believe one solution would be to seed a random set of links then use this snippet to create more links up to pre determined number of links.

Comment: Is there one specific aspect of this you really need help with? (For example, where did you get stuck exactly in trying to use the Preferential Attachment?) You've pretty much described your entire project here, so it's hard to know what to say. Writing a full response would take an hour; you'll probably need to ask something smaller someone can help with in 5 or 10 minutes.

Comment: Apologies for not being more specific I'll edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Of this snippet of code:

```
to-report find-partner
  report [one-of both-ends] of one-of links
end
```

you asked "Is this based on the number of links a node already has thus causing the preferential attachment?"

The answer is yes. But understanding why is a bit subtle. Instead of picking a node directly first we pick a random link, and then use it to lead us to a node. Why does this work?

Well, for example, suppose node A has 100 links connected to it, but node B only has one link connected to it. If we pick a link at random, it's 100 times likelier we'll pick a link connected to A, than a link connected to B. And that's exactly our goal — for a node's chance of being picked to be exactly proportional to its link count.

Comment: So calling the make-node procedure creates a new node depending on the degree of the current nodes. With regards to my problem would it work to create a set number of turtles of different breeds. Create a random amount of links then use find partner to begin building towards a scale free network like so....

Comment: Sure, that sounds feasible to me.

Comment: Basically all I would need to do is edit make node to create links between my three different types of nodes depending on which node is selected by find partner?

Comment: Sounds feasible to me. Try it and if you get stuck, post a new question.